# how to remove parent div when click on child inner anchor element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is my html code for aove fig.....
when i click on delete (id ="outdelete") total div (id="rightoutimage") should be deleted.......................

```
   <div id="rightoutputimgae">
           <div id="rightimgId" class="rightimg"  rel="tooltip" content="<img src='jqe13/image/1.jpg' class='tooltip-image'/> ">
                <div id="outputimageId" class="outputimage"><img src="jqe13/image/1.jpg" alt="Right Bottom Image">
                </div>
           </div>
      <ul>
          <li id="outcheckbox"><input name="outCheck" type="checkbox"></li>
          <li id="outedit"><a href="#"><img src="jqe13/image/edit_s.PNG" alt="edit"      title="Edit"></a></li>
          <li id="outdelete"><a href="#" onClick="deleteImg(outdelete)"> <img src="jqe13/image/delet_c.PNG" alt="delete" title="Delete"></a></li>
           <li id="outfullscreen"><a href="#"><img src="jqe13/image/fullscreen_c.PNG" alt="Full Screen" class="fullscreen" title="Full Screen"></a></li>
           <li id="outshare"><a href="#"><img src="jqe13/image/share_c.PNG" alt="Share" title="Share"></a>
        <div id="menu">
          <div id="tooltip_menu">
              <a href="#" class="menu_top" id="email"> <img src="jqe13/image/email.PNG"   alt="Email" title="Email"></a>
              <a href="#" onClick="postToFeed()" class="facebook"><img src="jqe13/image/fb.PNG" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook"></a>
              <a href="#" id="twitter"><img src="jqe13/image/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter"></a>
              <a href="#" class="menu_bottom" id="save"><img src="jqe13/image/save.PNG" alt="Save" title="Save"></a>
          </div>
        </div>
           </li>
           <li id="outprint"><a href="#"><img src="jqe13/image/print.PNG" class="printMe" alt="Print"  title="Print"></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

this is my scripting code........

```
<script>
   function deleteImg(id11) {
      id11 = document.getElementById("outdelete");
      $('#+id11').remove();
   }
</script>
```

Comment: `'#+id11'` should be `'#outdelete'`

Comment: `$('#+id11')` when your working with Jquery this complicated statement is not req, instead you can simply write it as `$('#outdelete')`. Jquery lib is created to write less code and do more, so make the most of it, dont write raw javascript code

Comment: `<div ... content="<img `? Oh my...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
$('#outdelete > a').click(function(){
   $(this).closest('#rightoutputimgae').remove();
});
```

Comment: Don't use `div#rightoutputimgae`. It means that jQuery needs to do more work, not only fetch element by ID but also check it's tag name, which is unnecessary.

Comment: See this: http://jsfiddle.net/e6t2n/. Working for me. Clikc on the delete img and it will remove the total div.

Comment: Please explain what do you mean? Not able to get you?

Comment: if i click the outdelete that div(rightoutimg) deleted ......but click the outdelete button  beside div also deleted ...........

Comment: By deside div you mean the div with ID `menu`?

Comment: suppose 4 divs r there ..4 divs having its own functions.....when i click first div delete button its remove closest div also.......accrd to above code.....

Comment: Please try to reproduce your issue on http://jsfiddle.net/ and I will have a look into it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#outdelete').click(function(){
   $("#rightoutputimgae").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
<li id="outdelete"><a href="#" onClick="deleteImg(outdelete)">
```

to:

```
<li id="outdelete"><a href="#" onClick="deleteImg(this)">
```

and your JS code:

```
<script>
   function deleteImg(self) {
        $(self).parents('#rightoutputimgae').get(0).remove();
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option for you, which you can see a working example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/TdLSy/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("li a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).find('img').remove();
    });
});
```

Along with your original HTML code:

```
  <div id="rightoutputimgae">
       <div id="rightimgId" class="rightimg"  rel="tooltip" content="<img src='jqe13/image/1.jpg' class='tooltip-image'/> ">
            <div id="outputimageId" class="outputimage"><img src="jqe13/image/1.jpg" alt="Right Bottom Image">
            </div>
       </div>
  <ul>
      <li id="outcheckbox"><input name="outCheck" type="checkbox"></li>
      <li id="outedit"><a href="#"><img src="jqe13/image/edit_s.PNG" alt="edit"      title="Edit"></a></li>
          <li id="outdelete"><a href="#" onClick="deleteImg()"> <img src="jqe13/image/delet_c.PNG" alt="delete" title="Delete" /></a></li>
       <li id="outfullscreen"><a href="#"><img src="jqe13/image/fullscreen_c.PNG" alt="Full Screen" class="fullscreen" title="Full Screen"></a></li>
       <li id="outshare"><a href="#"><img src="jqe13/image/share_c.PNG" alt="Share" title="Share"></a>
    <div id="menu">
      <div id="tooltip_menu">
          <a href="#" class="menu_top" id="email"> <img src="jqe13/image/email.PNG"   alt="Email" title="Email"></a>
          <a href="#" onClick="postToFeed()" class="facebook"><img src="jqe13/image/fb.PNG" alt="Facebook" title="Facebook"></a>
          <a href="#" id="twitter"><img src="jqe13/image/twitter.png" alt="Twitter" title="Twitter"></a>
          <a href="#" class="menu_bottom" id="save"><img src="jqe13/image/save.PNG" alt="Save" title="Save"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
       </li>
       <li id="outprint"><a href="#"><img src="jqe13/image/print.PNG" class="printMe" alt="Print"  title="Print"></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
document.getElementById("rightoutimage").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
      if(e.target.id === "outdelete") {
          var parent = e.target.parentNode;
          parent.parentNode.removeChild(parent);
      }   
});
```